# Organizar elementos de web en comun a traves de includes en un JSP

Tags: bootstrap, jsp

Tengo un sistema web hecho en java, en el cual esta fusionado con strut, de modo que cada pagina pasa a traves de strut y se redirecciona sin hacer una recarga de su menu principal, a diferencia de las tipicas paginas web que recargan una nueva pagina cada vez.

Ahora necesito traspasar ese sistema a Bootstrap y tengo una plantilla comprada para ello, pero no se como integrar esto, ya que bootstrap recarga cada pagina nueva, y cada pagina contiene  el mismo menu repetido. Es por ello que estoy viendo como generar una sola pagina con el menu o elementos en comun y llamarlos en los JSP a traves de includes, pero el gran problema es que no se como acomodarlos en la pagina (que el menu quede en la izquierda y no se superponga sobre la pantalla principal), de modo que al entrar a una pantalla desde el menu, este menu cargue el JSP, pero este JSP tenga el mismo menu incluido a traves de los includes bien organizados.

Quien me podria dar una idea de ello?
O quizas una mejor alternativa?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: No conozco JSP, pero sí sé que Bootstrap de por sí no recarga las páginas. Bootstrap es un framework que te permite estructurar tu HTML de manera más rápida, y cuenta con una buena base de CSS para que tengas menos trabajo al empezar un proyecto. Tu sistema web en Java seguramente ya tenga su HTML armado modularmente. Lo único que tenés que hacer es verificar que los archivos .js y .css de Bootstrap estén en el header global, y deberías poder usar sus componentes modularmente en combinación con lo actual.

Comment: Mucha sgracias victoria, justamente esta hecho con HTML modluado, fijo, que se llama al inicio mediante iframes, entonces este iframe mantiene quietos el menu lateral y superior, pero el centro o content, cambia segun el menu que escojamos a traves del strut quien organiza los JSP, de ese modo el menu no se recarga, mas que solamente la pantalla q escogimos.
Como bootstrap al menos la plantilla q tengo cambia completamente de pagina tipo pagina.com/menu1.html, /menu2.html, esta recarga toda la pagina y un nuevo menu.
Esta algo complicado, aunque ya tengo incluido el bt en el header

Comment: La plantilla que tenés, vas a tener que cortarla en módulos y hacer que el menú esté en uno de los módulos que nunca se recargan. Los links luego los reescribes para que vayan a secciones manejadas por strut.

Comment: Exacto, estaba viendo prescindir de iframes y usar una llamada tipo ajax, que al parecer es lo mejor, pero aun no entiendo como fusionarla con strut. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No, iframes jamás! Si necesitás más ayuda, agregá código con tus intentos hasta ahora a tu pregunta, y seguramente la comunidad sepa guiarte mejor.

Comment: Es que el sistema estaba hecho con iframes. Intentare poner codigo pero igual sera dificil formarse una idea ya que los archivos son extensos, pero ahi vere mas o menos como explicar la idea. Muchas gracias Victoria!